# Spring MVC, Method level security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to restrict access to my controller, based on user role. Now i can do that using the security.xml file in a following way

```
<http use-expressions="true">
     <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole([ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER])" />
</http>
```

But I dont want to do it this way. Rather i will write

```
<http use-expressions="true">
     <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
</http>
```

and in the controller

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public String test() {
    return "test";
}

@RequestMapping("/testadmin")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public String testAdminPage() {
    return "testadmin";
}
```

now ROLE_USER can access both (ROLE_ADMIN & ROLE_ USER) tagged controller. this is the problem. 
and based on this `testadmin.jsp` can only be viewed by ROLE_ADMIN type user and `test.jsp` can only be viewed by "ROLE_USER" type user.

To sum up rather than writing the access code in the xml file i want to control it from the controller.

How do i do this??

Comment: and what exactly does not work?

Comment: ROLE_USER can access both (ROLE_ADMIN & ROLE_ USER) tagged controller. this is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to enable method level security via

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

then your spring controllers are going to get proxied and the `PreAuthorize` annotation is going to be evaluated.

further information can be found here (section 16.3):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/el-access.html

EDIT:

I guess your `Controller` beans are being created in the Disptacher Servlet (the web-context) and your security configuration is in the root-context -> Controllers will stay unaffected by the `BeanPostProcessor` so you have to put the `<global-method-security>`tag in the web context config (dispatcher-servlet.xml?)

Comment: I tried this already this does not work. if i do this any type authenticated user can view any controller. ROLE_USER can access ROLE_ADMIN tagged controller.

Comment: yeah you are right i had to put in in web context config. thanks